# Lenovo ThinkBook 15-IML fingerprint not working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I have a problem with fingerprint on my laptop Lenovo ThinkBook 15-IML.
I have updated the BIOS to the latest version. After that, I have installed Ubuntu 19.10.
The touchpad problems are fixed, but the fingerprint reader is not working...
All of the GUI says that "the devices not found".
Any solution?

Comment: 19.10 Ubuntu version is currently installed

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that was provided by **Kai Heng-Feng**. You can apply the test kernel published in comment #88 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277 . It appears to work for me only that am not able to run my Virtualbox VMs as DKMS is not installed.

To apply this kernel you should download it and then go to Download folder and write the following sentence on a terminal:

sudo dpkg -i [linux-image-5.9.0-rc4+_5.9.0-rc4+-4_amd64.deb](https://people.canonical.com/%7Ekhfeng/lp1853277-hack-5/linux-image-5.9.0-rc4+_5.9.0-rc4+-4_amd64.deb)

Restart your computer, and enjoy your working touchpad!

I downloaded the linux-5.9-rc7 and recompiled it with kernel headers it compiled successfully with the exception of the DKMS for virtualbox. If you have no need for Virtualbox then it works fine.

#### Instruction for compiling ensure you have build-essentials installed

1. mkdir kernel; cd kernel;
2. wget the file
3. tar xvf linux-
4. cd linux-; make menuconfig
5. save the .config file
6. make -j 5 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.ribalinux deb-pkg # wait because is gonna take a while
7. sudo dpkg -i ../linux-*.deb
8. the reboot into the new kernel

Have fun

NOTE: This was only tested on Lenovo Thinkbook IIL series. Maybe the permanent solution will come bundled with Ubuntu 21.04 or maybe 20.10 in the future.

PS

Comment: sorry, gent,but I have asked about the fingerprint ....

Comment: I think you have to wait for Ubuntu 20.10... I see it comes pre-built with support for finger print login

Comment: I think so too, btw thanks for trying to help